# Does the word "besides" have two senses belonging to one semantic field?

Tags: meaning-in-context, prepositions, adverbs, semantics, semantic-shift

The term "besides" can mean

1. "apart from"; "other than";
   "I have no friends besides Maria."
   "I have nothing besides a car."
2. "in addition (to)"; "as well (as)"; "moreover".
   "I can cook, and a lot more besides".
   "I dislike tennis, besides, I do not even own a tennis racquet."

Do both senses of this term fall within the same semantic field?

> Love is the essence of the world as appearance and love is what the world is besides appearance.

How can something (love) be the essence of the world as appearance, and also be what the world is besides (apart from) appearance?

Comment: The same meaning applies to *I have **no** friends **in addition to** Maria* (she ***is*** my only friend) and *I can cook, and [I can do] a lot more **in addition to** [being able to cook]* (that ***is not*** the only thing I can do). I think maybe you're confusing yourself by switching between "direct positive assertions" and ***negating*** contexts.

Comment: (Your sentence *Love is the essence of the world as appearance and love is what the world is besides appearance* doesn't mean anything to me. It's just playing with words.)

Comment: 1) The question title uses "beside" rather than "besides." Is that a mistake? It was used for meaning 1 in archaic usage, though not for 2 as far as I know. 2) Maybe I'm just ignorant, but can you define "semantic field"? 3) Is the quoted sentence your own? If you found it somewhere, can you say where and give some context? It's quite poetic/esoteric, making a paradox out of abstract concepts, and difficult to pin down exactly which sense it intends (if not both).

Comment: For your first question, both definitions say that "besides" is used for *separate from*. They are very close. For your quote, well it's poetic, and yet more besides appearing so.

Comment: the term in questions is "besides". My error with the title.

Comment: Semantic field: essentially a set of terms with related meanings. ""The words in a semantic field share a common semantic property. Most often, fields are defined by subject matter, such as body parts, landforms, diseases, colors, foods, or kinship relations..."

Comment: with respect to the quoted sentence,  I did not find this in text anywhere, although I heard a lecturer say this when talking of Plato. With "the world of appearance" I am referencing Plato's analogy.  He talks about the Forms behind appearance (empirical knowledge of the world via the senses).   The statement seemed to be a contradiction which was due to the use of the term "besides."

Comment: FumbleFingers: so do you think it is one and the same sense of "besides"?

Comment: I think you need to explain you question further by at least citing the source and the general nature of the claim(s) being made.  I can get the general idea that it is representing the 'world' as in some way consisting of appearance and in some other way involving 'love'.  As rux23 says, there seem to be echoes of a world of appearance discussed in many of Plato's works.   It is also the case that 'love'  seems to have featured in the ideas of some presocratic thinkers as a way of accounting for the attraction needed to enable matter to coalesce.  But without a specific context, that's it.

Comment: You have two different propositions here: **1.** Love is the essence of "the world as appearance" (love is at the heart of that Kantian construct).  **2.** Love is what the world is other than appearance (the world = love + appearance).

Comment: @TinfoilHat yes agreed.  They appear to contradict each other.

Comment: @TinfoilHat  so, in the first proposition. 1. Love is within the world of appearance. To be the essence of something entails that it is "within" or bound to that something. So Love is within, bound to, appearance as its essence.                                                                                                                          But with 2. Love is what the world is besides appearance....so there is appearance, and there is love which is outside of- besides- appearance.

Comment: I don't think it's contradictory — just a bit of a non sequitur. You have *world-of-appearance* (a concept) and *appearance*. Two different things. Like this: *Love is the essence of cats and love is what the world is besides appearance.*

Comment: Weren’t you banned?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the original supposition is incorrect:

"apart from"; "other than";
"I have no friends besides Maria."

<s>"in addition (to)"; "as well (as)"; "moreover".</s>
"I can cook, and a lot more <s>besides</s> **apart from/other than** [cook - *implied*]"

Comment: Thanks. So, in essence, we are really only dealing with one single sense with the term "besides."?

Comment: That is how I see it.